# Can't read 10 digit integer value in Matlab GUI edit text

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am using matlab 2013 version, and I am not able to read 10 digit phone number from a edit text field. It is only reading 8 digit number. What can I do?

```
input=str2double(get(hobject,'string'));
 if isnan(input)
  errordlg('You must enter a numeric value','Invalid Input','modal')
  uicontrol(hObject)
  return
else
  display(input);
end
```

Comment: what is hObject ? Please provide some codethat we can actually run.

Comment: It worked fine for me having more than 8 characters in an edit string. I think that the problem lies elsewhere. is it the `display(input);` that give you something you do not expect? To be able to help an answer to this is required.

Comment: What is the type of gui element you are using to record the info?  `inputdlg` works fine for me: 
    `answer=str2double(inputdlg('Digits please:')); 
    display(answer)`